# How to check runtime error of a program in bash?

Tags: bash

I made a C program that would throw **segmentation fault** error whenever I run it. And then I made a bash script as follows:

```
cat input.txt | ./a.out 1> output.txt 2> error.txt
cat error.txt
```

The output of the second line should have been something like *segmentation error (core-dumped)*
But instead it's a blank file.

How do I capture the runtime errors of a C program?

Comment: What is the operator precedence of the pipe and stderr-redirection operators?

Comment: @Dai , sorry, I didn't get your question. Can you simplify it?

Comment: Avoid unnecessary use of `cat` (e.g. `./a.out <input.txt >output.txt 2>error.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact that the `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` message is **not** generated *by your program*, it is generated by the shell in which you can the `a.out` command.  The process looks approximately like this:

- Your program generates a segfault
- Your program receives a `SIGSEGV` signal
- Your program exits
- The `wait()` system call executed by your shell exits with a status code that indicates your program exited abnormally due to a `SIGSEGV` signal.
- The shell prints an error message

This is discussed in somewhat more detail in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257665/4989).

If you want to capture this output, you can try something like:

```
$ sh -c 'trap "" 11; ./a.out' 1> output.txt 2> error.txt
$ cat error.txt
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This will run your code in a subprocess and will inhibit the default handling of the segfault by the shell.

Comment: What's does the *"" 11;* do inside the trap?

Comment: `man bash` has the answer: "If arg  is the null string the signal specified by each sigspec is ignored by the shell and by the commands it invokes."